# How can I add CSS file in django

Tags: css, django

django 2.1

[Im using django 2.1 and i cant find my css folder in django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J72No.png)

Comment: It's helpful to add what you've tried and what you have found when you have done research.

Answer (score 0):

Create new file and add `.css` after the name which is basically your file extension name.

Your css files must be in `app > static > appname folder > css > filename`

File hierarchy should be like this as django prefers.